# Windows 7 - window dragging vertically when panning on overscroll - can it be disabled?

Tags: windows-7, scrolling, touch

I have a Windows 7 touch screen computer. I noticed that when I have windowed applications which are vertically scrollable, for example Windows Task manager, and I scroll (with touch) to the bottom and try to scroll further, the window moves vertically and then snaps back into place.

I can disable panning using Group Policy and then I can't scroll with touch. I would like to keep scrolling on touch, but disable the moving of the window vertically when I overscroll.

Is there a way to disable this 'over-scroll' behavior in Windows 7?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/533388/windows-7-window-moving - this helped me out

Comment: How is that question related to this one? They seem to be completely different issues. In what way did that help?