# Windows 8.1: Allow Real-Time Resizing

Tags: windows-8.1, window

Recently, I installed [EaseUS Partition manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/), and ever since then, both resizing and dragging windows does not behave as it used to; I simply get a placeholder, and the window does not resize in real-time:

[image]

How can I fix this?  Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you turn on and off window repaint while drag moving/re-sizing window in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/175448/how-do-you-turn-on-and-off-window-repaint-while-drag-moving-re-sizing-window-in), [Windows 7: window moving](http://superuser.com/questions/533388/windows-7-window-moving)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [on a forum here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/216705-window-resizing-not-real-time.html).

1. Search "Advanced System", and select **Show Advanced System Settings**
2. Navigate to the **Advanced** tab
3. Open up the **Settings** menu under the **Performance** fieldset
4. Select **Custom**, and enable all effects

[image]

Comment: Specifically "Show windows contents while dragging".